# How to restore the last trashed file using a non-interactive command?

Tags: command-line, restore, trash

Say I just moved a file to trash from a file manager or using a command-line implementation such as `kioclient move my_file trash:/`.

Can I restore it with a single, non-interactive command?

[trash-cli](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli) can restore files, but only (I believe) by selecting them interactively.

Answer (score 0):

[trashy](https://github.com/oberblastmeister/trashy) allows this:

```bash
trash restore -fr 0
```

To restore the last N files (indexes from 0 included to N excluded):

```bash
trash restore -fr 0..N
```

Remove `-f` to get interactive confirmation:

```bash
trash restore -r 0
```